# Catch2 undefined reference to Catch::StringMaker

Tags: c++, catch2

I am using Catch2 from the actual `devel` branch and I have a linker error when trying to compare two `vector<string_view>`

The issue can be reproduced as following:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string_view>
#include <catch2/catch_test_macros.hpp>

TEST_CASE("Can split string", "[split]") {
  vector<string_view> splittedString = {"this is a string view"sv};
  vector<string_view> EXPECTED = {"I'm"sv, "Elvis"sv,"Dukaj"sv};
  REQUIRE(splittedString == EXPECTED);
}
```

My `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
find_package(Catch2 REQUIRED)
# ...
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE  Catch2::Catch2WithMain)
```

When trying to build I have the following linker error:

```
Catch2/src/catch2/../catch2/catch_tostring.hpp:126: error: undefined reference to `Catch::StringMaker<std::basic_string_view<char, std::char_traits<char> >, void>::convert[abi:cxx11](std::basic_string_view<char, std::char_traits<char> >)'
```

What am I doing wrong? Am I missing some includes?

Comment: I think matchers were split to separate header, try including `catch2/catch_matchers_all.hpp` as well.

Comment: "What am I doing wrong?" - why are you building from their `develop` branch? That's not intended for production use.

Comment: @Dai this is not production code :) Anyway I switched to `v2.x` branch and chaneged the include with `#include <catch2/catch.hpp>` and I have still the same problem.

Comment: @Resurrection there is no such header file in Catch2 neither from v2 and devel branch

Comment: That header exists in the sources, hm. Anyway, I recall having a problem with `std::string_view` matcher as well. I think it was limited to C++17 in the Catch2 sources and I was using some combination like Clang on Windows that was not recognized by that.

Comment: @Dai anyw the `develop` branch is the old `master` so is something that is super stable in theory

Comment: @Resurrection I added also `#include <catch2/matchers/catch_matchers_all.hpp>` but the problem is still here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Solution

You need to build Catch with C++17 support to be able to use string_view inside REQUIRE() and other macros. By default, Catch is built with C++14 for some reason.

To do so you can run this in directory with your Catch sources:

```bash
mkdir build && cd build
cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_STANDARD=17 ..
sudo make install
```

### Notes

1. You are heavily relying on Catch2 v3 features, so you should use `find_package(Catch2 3 REQUIRED)` instead of just `find_package(Catch2 REQUIRED)` in your cmake file
2. You can see discussions of the issue [here](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/issues/2046) and [here](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/issues/2210)